# AWS Amplify Authentication with phone number only

Tags: database, react-native, aws-amplify, mobile-application, aws-amplify-cli

I'm trying to create an authentication for mobile app like whatsapp. The users can login with their phone number and will get an sms for verification.

I have looked up endless tutorials, so all of them are with email, so anyone can help me out with any tutorials?

I'm using react native.

Thanks a lot, programmers